# Ruby on Rails - Forbidden Attributes on params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes

Im trying to redirect someone after they click a button and I keep getting the following error:

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Extracted source (around line #20):

It is throwing the error on the @post = Post.new line.

```
def create   
@post = Post.new(params[:post])

if @post.save
 redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post was saved"
```

I am very new to Ruby and at the moment I am very confused of what this means. I am just following a tutorial and mine isnt working. If anyone could help that would be awesome :D

Comment: What rails version are you using? If you are using 4.0 or later and if the tutorial is using pre rails 4 version then probably it does't account for strong params which is now used.

Comment: I am using 4.1.1, what do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have quite enough of your code to specifically answer the question, I can probably get pretty close (minus some column/attribute naming). With strong_params now the standard for Rails applications, you'd probably be looking to do something more like:

```
def create   
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post was saved"
  else
    #other stuff here
  end
end

private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:content, ....etc) #I took a guess at the attributes you are passing through your params on the create.
end
```

For a little extra easy-reading on the history/reason: http://blog.8thlight.com/will-warner/2014/04/05/strong-parameters-in-rails.html

Let me know if you'd like any additional clarification.

Comment: Looks like Steve beat me to the punch. His answer is correct, but check and make sure your attributes match the names of your columns in your model - like me, he just took a guess.

Comment: What does it mean to have them matching the names of the columns? As I said Im very new to Ruby and im having troubles understanding this

Comment: So, the columns I was referring to are from your table called Posts - the attributes for Posts are columns in your table. These columns/attributes are managed by your ActiveRecord Post model. In Post.new, you're passing parameters that correspond to the attributes/columns for a Post so it can save the values for this new post in the corresponding database columns. Each new post fills in new values for each of those columns. In a post, I'd guess there could be columns/attributes like a :subject, :content, and maybe a :link or :photo or things of the like.

Answer (score 3):

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
```

... is no longer used in the latest versions of rails.  The problem is that it provided weak security.  Someone who was updating their user profile (for example) could theoretically insert an attribute like "administrator: true" to change themselves into an administrator (if that's how admin flag is stored)

Strong parameters now require that you explicity specify which attributes you want to allow to be entered.

So nowadays we do...

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```

And we have a method later in the controller that specifies the permitted attributes, and looks like...

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

Comment: When I do that it gives me an undefined local variable or method error

Comment: And the variable or method it's complaining about is `post_params` ?  As I mentioned, you have to add the method `post_params` as a separate method in your controller.

Comment: Whats supposed to go inside the permit()

Comment: All the attributes that you want to accept. If you've been following a tutorial, it must have had you make a form for new and edit under your app/views/posts directory. Maybe called new.html.erb ... the form included various fields... maybe a post title, maybe a post body, I can't be sure without seeing that file. Basically, every field you defined on that form that you eventually want stored in the model should be listed in the permit. List them as symbols (meaning they each start with a colon) and separate them with commas.

Comment: If you want to modify your question to include your app/views/posts/new.html.erb file we could give more specific advice. If your tutorial coached you to create a `partial` (shared code) that was included in both your new and edit views, include that partial in your answer instead.